# Inscribed angle theorem for hyperbolic sectors

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I did the following easy exercise [in 2020](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=7300):

> Points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are on a circle with centre $O$.
>
> The lines through $O$ parallel to $AC$ and $BC$ intersect the circle at $D$ and $E$.
>
> Then the area of the sector $AOB$ is twice the area of the sector $DOE$.
> [image]

It is true for conic sections in general:

> Points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are on a hyperbola with centre $O$.
>
> The lines through $O$ parallel to $AC$ and $BC$ intersect the hyperbola at $D$ and $E$.
>
> Then the area of the sector $AOB$ is twice the area of the sector $DOE$.
> [image]

Can we deduce the hyperbola case from the circle case through some geometric transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after.  There is the hyperbolic interpretation of the parameter $t$ in $(\cosh t,\sinh t)$ as twice the (signed) area swept by the radial sector analogous to the circular version $(\cos t,\sin t)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, I know the hyperbolic interpretation. But I was thinking about mapping the circle to the hyperbola. I added an image. The circle case can be easily proven using$$2\angle DOE=2\angle ACB=\angle AOB$$

Comment: Affine transformations map circle to ellipse, unfortunately it can't map circle to hyperbola. So the circle case implies the ellipse case but doesn't imply the hyperbola case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying a suitable affine transformation we can assume that the hyperbola is given by $xy=1$ and $C=(-1,-1)$. Let $F=(1,1)$. It is enough to prove that the area of sector $FOB$ equals twice the area of sector $FOE$. (We prove in a similar way that the area of $AOF$ equals twice the area of sector $DOF$, from which the result follows.)

Let $E=(s,\frac 1s)$. As shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_sector), the area of sector $FOE$ equals $\ln s$. Similarly, if $B=(t,\frac 1t)$ then the area of sector $FOB$ equals $\ln t$. We have to prove that $\ln t = 2\ln s$, which is equivalent to $t=s^2$.

Note that the line $OE$ has equation $y=\frac{1}{s^2}x$. By assumption, the line $BC$ is parallel to $OE$, hence $BC$ has equation $y=\frac{1}{s^2}x+u$ for some $u$. Since $C=(-1,-1)$, we have $-1=\frac{1}{s^2}\cdot(-1)+u$, hence $u=-1+\frac{1}{s^2}$. We have $\frac 1t = \frac{1}{s^2}t-1+\frac{1}{s^2}$. This is a quadratic equation in $t$ with roots $-1$ and $s^2$. Since $B\neq C$, we have $t\neq -1$, hence $t=s^2$ and we are done.

Comment: C is an arbitrary point on the hyperbola. Can you explain why we can map C to a chosen point $(−1,−1)$ by affine transformation? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I realize the affine transformation$$(x,y)↦(-λ^{-1}x,-λy)$$maps point $(λ,λ^{-1})$ to $(-1,-1)$ while mapping the hyperbola to itself